# How to display tooltip in center of screen?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, controls, tooltip

I'm using C# and I want to display a tooltip in the center of the screen instead of using `MessageBox` for some trivial tasks, such as showing exceptions and things like that.

How to do that? The problem is that tooltips always show near a control (like `button1`, `form1`, etc.).

Here is what I used:

```
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Show("show tooltip", this, 1500);
```

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this... but using tooltips in such a fashion is very unusual and therefore *might* confuse users of your program. A more common approach might be tray notifications (the ones that usually appear in the bottom right corner of the screen for a few seconds, then slowly fade out).

Comment: ... yes but i wouldn't use those in application it's for some other tasks..

Comment: Just some clarification, would you want the tooltip to show even if the application is minimized ?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I see problems though. Like the tooltip being on top of the control which has focus. Also the awful possibilty, of them hanging around, when moving the form about, multiple ones being up at the same time, and one horrible I've see before. Them somehow getting detached from the parent and the only way to get rid, is to kill the entire app.

Comment: Well i need those for testing for some small and speed application which mean that it need to be called from other thread so that basiclly mean yes i need it also when it's minimized ... but don't have to delete answare .. i  really appricieate effort of programers

Answer (score 4):

Use the overloaded [ToolTip.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tksk5312.aspx) and set the [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/s9b80s6c.aspx) where you want to show the tooltip. Example :

```
TooleTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Show("show tooltip", new Point(x, y), this, 1500);
```

Where `x` and `y` should be near the center of the form. Please note that the tooltip is shown relative to the form. So it won't be useful if the application is minimized. And like others said, its not a good idea after all. You could create some custom window that shows and hides after sometime.

See [Form Fade In/Out Effect and Notification Window](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c10139/Form-Fade-InOut-Effect-and-Notification-Window.htm)

Comment: this point is always relative to the parent. It's impossible to show the tooltip at the screen center, if the form is minimized

Comment: @VladL The OP hasn't mentioned such possibility, so my answer is very relative to the question requirement.

Comment: The OP's title is "How to display tooltip in center of screen" so your answer will work in a very limited number of situations